# Why can't I use pushViewController with UIButton?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, xcode4, pushviewcontroller

I want to use pushViewController but I can't. I remember that I can use this code in xcode3.

Here is  code in IBAction Button

```
-(IBAction)changtoCal:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"get in");
    UINavigationController *cal_nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNibName:@"calculator" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:cal_nav animated:YES];
}
```

It don't push. Why ??? Could you tell me and how can I push it ???

And here is my AppDelegate 
.h

```
@class ViewController;

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [_window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the `UIViewController` is not correctly embedded in the `UINavigationController`. That would mean that `self.navigationController = nil`.

I do not know the XIB, but you could fix it by doing the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController *navc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    self.window.rootViewController = navc;
    [_window addSubview:navc.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: sry, It crash and show.
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Pushing a navigation controller is not supported'

Comment: Got it. When I combine beryllium and FelixLam together I can push that. Thank you you two :)))

Answer (score 2):

You should create instance of your custom UIViewController in IBAction, not an new UINavigationController

```
// change UICalculatorViewController to your view controller
UICalculatorViewController *cal_nav = [[UICalculatorViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"calculator" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:cal_nav animated:YES];
```

Comment: Got it. When I combine beryllium and FelixLam together I can push that. Thank you you two :)))